# Binding a SelectedItem in a list box to a KeyValuePair<>

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a list box bound to an ObservableDictionary (custom class, left out for brevity) class.  And it is working great except for the binding on the SelectedItem. I have the following property bound to the selectedItem of the ListBox.

```
public KeyValuePair<Bumpstop, BumpStopOptions> SelectedBumpstop
    {
        get
        {
            return this.selectedBumpstop;
        }
        set
        {
            this.selectedBumpstop = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedBumpstop");
        }
    }
```

When I select an item in my list box it hits the set property and it works.  When I unselect everything the ListBox gets the RedBorder around it indicating a binding failure and it does not set the SelectedBumpstop property to null like I would expect.  Why does it not set it to null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Red border is not a binding failure (in the sense of binding errors found in the VS Output box), it is a validation failure.

The bindings automatically check if the new value is acceptable for the binding source type (in this case the `KeyValuePair`). No value selected would mean `null` as selected value, which is not valid for `KeyValuePair` - it is a structure, which are value types, therefore can't posess a `null` value. So the validation fails and the value is not uploaded to the source.

Making the type [nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) (`KeyValuePair<Bumpstop, BumpStopOptions>?`) will fix this, but it can have ramifications for your other code, so think this through carefully (you may have to add nullity checks wherever the property is used).

Comment: Thanks for explaining this.  This def. answered my question and your fix works beautifully.